# populate both source and target in Sequelize associations

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm learning postgreSQl/Sequelize.

In my app I have a one to many relationship between `company` and `user`:

```
User.belongsTo(Company, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
Company.hasMany(User);
```

When I create a user with `company.createUser()` the user automatically receives the `companyId` as foreign key.
Is it possible to also auto-populate `company` with an array of users, pushing every newly created user onto it?

Or do I need to do it more 'manually'?

Or do I simply not do it and instead query my user table with `{where: companyId: <companyId>}`?

EDIT:
I see now that Sequelize generates the `getUsers()` function on company. So I can call `company.getUsers()`. This way I decide if/when I want the users.

I can also query:

```
Company.findOne({ where: { id: companyId }, include: ['users'] });
```

to always get users.

So I guess the company table **is** auto-populated. However, I don't see a users column in pgAdmin nor in the postgres shell. Should I see it? If not, can I make it visible?

Comment: It seems you need to look deeper into relational DB concept and how tables are linked to each other. That way you will learn that `user` table will have `companyId` column and `company` table won't have any columns related to users.

Comment: Yes, I found out. Thanks.